# Wiring a switch to a new power supply for a 12v lamp

Tags: switches, wiring

I am trying to fix a sign that wouldn't light up anymore and I got confused when it came to installing the actual switch. It does work now but with the "fix" (replaced electronics of the sign with a new power supply) I have no idea where the switch goes.

So originally it had a lightbar in the back of the housing, with two wires +/- going to a board. That board also had 4 wires going to a switch and two more wires +/- that went out to the wall plug.

I disconnected the lightbar from the board and hooked it to a generic 12V power supply that's just a wall plug with 12V/1A output where I cut the dc plug off so I have the + and - wires. Now the light works when it's directly on the power supply but where does the switch go? The switch I have has 4 pins, but don't I only need to switch the one "+" wire coming from the power supply? I don't understand how that switch would be hooked up. I also don't know if I can just put the switch between the power supply and the light or if I need one between the power supply and the wall power socket.

Is this even possible with that switch or do I have to get a new one? Maybe that switch only works with that board because it did have 4 wires. I don't get what it had 4 wires for when it still works now with 2, do I need to split both to get 4 for the switch? If yes, wouldn't I need to split the wires on the lightbar as well?

I know I can give that up and plug the new power supply into a power strip that has a switch and then use that to turn power on/off for everything but that would look awful and the idea was to keep as much of the original installation as possible. I also want to understand this more so I explained as good as I can, I'm sorry if the question is stupid.

I have a photo of that switch. Please someone tell me how or if it can be wired or if I'm wrong and what else I should buy instead??

[image]

Comment: Choose a better user name.

Comment: if possible can you provide a part number or a datasheet for the switch? knowing the voltage and current it can theoretically handle.

Answer (score 0):

The switch has 2 poles - Meaning it's basically two switches in one package.

Pins marked "1/2" is the first switch, and the pins marked "4/5" is the second switch.

It had 4 wires because the original setup would cut both the AC Hot & Neutral lines.

For safety, it's really only necessary to cut the hot, but you never know if the wall outlet is wired right, so the even safer option is to use a switch that cuts both.  Hence 4 wires instead of 2.

In your repair, you can cut either the AC input or the DC 12V.   The difference is, if you cut the DC, the power supply will always be running and consuming a trickle of energy.